# E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while installing a package

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to install latex in 17.04 using

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full texmaker
```

but it returns

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: it seems another process is running an update or something. Did you try to reboot? Sometimes Ubuntu is running an automatic update and therefore the dpkg is locked for a certain time

Comment: And do you really need texlive-full? Usually it is better to just install texlive base and let texmaker download required packages on runtime to save a lot of diskspace

Answer (score 0):

You cant have more than 1 app installing at once, this includes updates, any `apt` commands or any other installers that use dpkg (.deb files too.)

if you dont have something like that open, try typing `ps -ef | grep apt` to see if anything is running.

Comment: Great! If you can hile it's flagged give it a point and a check!